# Testing OAuth 2.0 Protected Angular App with Cypress

Tags: angular, cypress, nrwl-nx

### Background

I'm trying to write some Cypress tests for my Angular application. The app is built in a monorepo with Nx, where Cypress was installed and set up for us automatically. We are using Identity Server 4 and OAuth2 to secure the Angular app. We're using the [angular-auth-oidc-client package from NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-auth-oidc-client) to handle the login/authentication. The app uses the Implicit Flow, so when you log in to the app you get sent to the auth server, enter your credentials, and are then redirected back to the Angular app. The callback URL after logging in and being redirected back to the Angular app is, at least in part,

```
/auth/calback#id_token=<token>
```

I'm not entirely sure the rest of the callback URL, but I believe (from what I could find) that it includes `token_type` (Bearer), `expires_in` (3600 in my case), and `state` (I don't know what should be placed there).

### Question

My question is how do I get the Angular app to be authenticated so that I can run the Cypress tests? I know that I can't do the implicit flow for real, so my plan was to get a token before each test with an HTTP request and manually enter that into the `/auth/callback` route of the Angular app, and that hopefully from there the Angular app would take over. Here's that setup:

```
cy.request(options).then((result: any) => {
  const { body: tokenInfo } = result;
  // I've used access_token and id_token, both with the same result
  cy.visit(
    `/auth/callback#id_token=${tokenInfo['access_token']}&token_type=${tokenInfo['token_type']}&expires_in=${tokenInfo['expires_in']}&state=some-fake-state`,
  );
});
```

I know for sure that the request is successful and returns the `access_token`, `token_type`, and `expires_in` values. But that's the last part of my spec file that seems to work.

After that, there are a couple other XHR requests made, for example to the auth server's well known endpoint. But after a handful of milliseconds those XHR calls are cancelled and the test goes forward from the `beforeEach` where the login is done. Here's a GIF of the test running:

[image: GIF of the tests running]

(I added a 5 second wait in the test just to see if it helped in any way. It doesn't.)

In the one test I have, I'm just trying to check if the person can see stuff on the page that requires them to be logged in. However, it fails each time.

I'm sure there's a way to do this, but I have hit a wall. If anyone has any ideas on how to do this, I'd be really grateful. I thought that [this tutorial on Auth0](https://auth0.com/blog/end-to-end-testing-with-cypress-and-auth0/#Writing-tests-using-Cypress-Login-Command) would get me there, but it wasn't quite enough to work. I've looked at several other resources, but none of them have all the information I need.

Comment: As a first check : are you running your tests against a local envirenement ? if not I suggest using a fully qualified url in `cy.visit('https://XXXXX/auth/callback#id_token=${tokenInfo['access_token']}&token_type=${tokenInfo['token_type']}&expires_in=${tokenInfo['expires_in']}&state=some-fake-state')`

Comment: "I know that I can't do the implicit flow for real" -- and why?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov *".. can't do the implicit flow for real"* because he does not have control over the UI nor the flow of the whole auth, since it interact with third parties. (ie: consider it as when you integrate Google Sign-In to your app, you won't automate the whole auth flow since you will need to interact with UI of google which you do not have any control over it .... -you could hack a way through this but it is not a good idea, it would be better to just interact with it programatically with calling some API, such as  suggested by pjlamb12 - )

Comment: @TarekBaz we have oauth with login on external site and we have e2e test doing that login. And just in case you can write test that logins to google -- why not? And if you dont want to that you can add basic or any other auth on server that u run test on and use it.